# Python list of dict not freeing memory after emptying list

Tags: python, multithreading, list, dictionary, memory-management

I have a python script in which there is a global variable `object_list`

I start 5 parallel threads calling a function to read `objects` from SQS and append to same list. Like below:-

```
object_list = []
def operate(obj_array):
    for obj in obj_array:
        # some calculation.
        # obj is of type dict.
        obj.clear()
    # either i can clear each object in the for loop or delete the obj_array at the end.
    del obj_array

def append_to_list(sqs):
    global object_list
    object_list.append(sqs)
    if len(object_list) > 100:
        o = Thread(target=operate, args=(object_list,))
        o.start()
        object_list = []

def object_reader(process_number):
    print process_number
    for msg in queue.get_messages():
        obj = json.loads(msg.get_body())
        t = Thread(target=append_to_list, args=(obj,))
        t.start()

for x in xrange(5):
    t = Thread(target=object_reader, args=(x,))
    t.start()
```

As show in the above code i want program to start 5 threads to read from SQS and append objects into one global list.

Once list length exceeded 100 i want to operate on that list in another thread and also making the global list empty to repeat the same.

The problem is that my program runs in a infinite loop (24x7) but the script memory keep increasing and exceeding the container limit which resulting in killing of container.

I don't know why the memory keep increasing as i am emptying the global list when it exceed size 100.

Comment: Is there an actual reason to use so many threads, though? You should probably try with 1 SQS reading thread that puts messages in a `queue.Queue()`, then 1 to N threads that read from that queue and do the `# some calculation` bit for a single message.

Comment: Reading from sqs is slow and max 10 messages comes in a batch. So by 5 reader threads i can read SQS fast and once i have enough objects to process i operate on them as operate is a heavy process and preforming it per-message is inefficient.

Comment: (Also, you should probably use a memory profiler to make sure the leak is where you expect it to be.)

Comment: Fair, so then use 5 reader threads, a queue and 1 to N calculation threads. Since it looks like `# some calculation` does not need a batch of objects, but works on one object at a time, I don't see why that would be any less efficient.

Comment: `# some calculation` needs to be on batch as the calculated result of the batch is to be save in DB. yes `# some calculation` works on one object at a time but the DB insertion is in batch.

Comment: @akx any guide on profiler that provide variable level memory info. I am new to profilers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181322/discussion-between-jugraj-singh-and-akx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a dangling reference to the object pointed to by the name `object_list`, so the object never gets garbage collected.

Doing `object_list = []` will assign a new empty list to the global name `object_list`, but not modify the existing, possibly dangling, list object pointed to by that name.

You might want to instead clear the entire list in-place by using slice assignment:

```
object_list[:] = []
```

Comment: But my operate function need the list in `object_array` variable to operate. will it destroy the list before operate has a chance to process it. my operate function is a bit slow as compare to the reader that's why i started it in separate thread.

Comment: please see the updated question i provide some context to operate function. will that help @akx